# Using third party libraries in Svelte custom component

Tags: web-component, custom-component, svelte, svelte-component

I want to create a web component using svelte. To create a web component it's necessary to include the svelte tag option

`<svelte:options tag="{"my-custom-component}"></svelte:options>`

It creates a custom component with that name but doesn't work properly because we have to provide this tag for all the child components as well! I added it to all the child components but it still doesn't work, turns out I use third-party libraries and I don't know any way to have that option there!

Is there a way to create the custom components with svelte which includes third-party libraries?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your question. This does Not affect your question sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You **can** use regular svelte components (including third party) ones inside your component.
But you'll need to compile those with different compiler settings in your rollup/webpack config.
And due to the nature of scoped styling in web components (Shadow DOM) the **css won't work** in these components. So it depends on the library if it still works.

You might be able to turn off scoped styling in the future:
[Issue #1748: Custom element without shadow DOM](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1748)

But scoped styling could have been the reason why you wanted/needed webcomponents in the first place.